# iPhone tabbar navigation goes to the wrong screen

Tags: iphone

In my application

1. When app. launch it's display loading screen.
2. After loading screen have another screen that contain 4 button.
3. If I select any button that after next screen (3 screen contain tabbar controller).

So now I want to pop (or back to second) screen, but due to the tabbar controller on 3rd screen I can't go to back on second screen that the problem I faced now.

When I select communicator it goes to AMG home. Now I want to back to communicator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do presentModalViewController with the help of that you can navigate back to your second screen:

```
homePageViewController = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:homePageViewController animated:NO];
[homePageViewController release];
```

homePageViewController is nothing but only the name of your second page.

Or

You have to use the following code if you are pushing the view.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: but that is not  particular  way to push from that view , i know about that but i want pop only if any way possible. thanks your support

Comment: could you show me the code how are you pushing your view... So, that i can help you some more....

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: here problem is only due to the tabbarcontroller , i can't pop because of tabbarcontroller is used.

Comment: if i select communicator icon i used this :  CommunicatorHome *objCommunicatorView=[[CommunicatorHome alloc]initWithNibName:@"CommunicatorHome" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:objCommunicatorView animated:YES];
 [objCommunicatorView release];  and after that i clickd back button than it goes to main page as show in pic.1

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  According to me this must be work. Otherwise check that have you handle the action event of button properly or not and also check that you have gave the IBAction connection to your IB file.

Comment: if i remove this  [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]; then it work's perfect.